# Inner select queries in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created as table as below

```
create table student (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100), time varchar(100));
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein', 'today');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton', 'today');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (3, 'marie', 'curie', 'today');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (4, 'Aneesh', 'pn', 'yesterday');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (5, 'joe', 'curie', 'yesterday');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (6, 'Aneesh', 'hahha', 'yesterday');
        insert into student (id, firstname, lastname, time) values (7, 'Aneesh', 'narayanan', 'today');
        select * from student;
```

Now I want to query the data based on the time
The query will be
The input is the time. Get all records matches with the input time, then take its first name and return all the records matching that first name.

Suppose I give time as 'yesterday', then it returns

```
id| firstname | lastname| time
-------------------------------
4 | Aneesh    | pn | yesterday
5 | joe       | curie | yesterday
6 | Aneesh    | hahha | yesterday
7 | Aneesh    | narayanan | today
```

I tried the below query but not worked. Some syntax errors

```
select (
                'Id',id,
                'FirstName',firstname,
                'LastName',lastname,
                'Time',time
          ) as json 
          from
            (
              select firstname from student
                where time= 'yesterday') as tt
             where firstname = tt.firstname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, obtain the fisrt *firstname* at the specified time, and then join this dataset with your table :

```
select firstname, time
from student
where time= 'yesterday'
order by id
limit 1
```

Use the condition `on f.time = s.time or f.firstname = s.firstname`, to ensures that the final result set can include records from your table that either have the same *firstname* as the first record found at the specified time or share the same time value, regardless of the *firstname*.

```
select  s.*
from student s
inner join (
  select firstname, time
  from student
  where time= 'yesterday'
  order by id
  limit 1
) as f on f.time = s.time or f.firstname = s.firstname;
```

Results :

```
id  firstname   lastname    time
4   Aneesh      pn          yesterday
5   joe         curie       yesterday
6   Aneesh      hahha       yesterday
7   Aneesh      narayanan   today
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2r6DKp-i)